# href and js to be worked work together on html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to open my href link and setting the padding of container of web page at same time.
My code is as

```
 <a href="/Link1/" onclick="return SizeOf(); "  >LinkText</a>

 function SizeOf() {
      document.getElementById("contain1").style.padding = "000px 150px 00px 210px";
  }
```

But for now either of them working.Either I can open my page or I can set the paddings using CSS.I want to do the both things i.e. open my page and set padding as well.
Please help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: it is unclear what you want, do you want to open a new window with new padding or what? can you post some example code please? :-)

Comment: if you want to go to another page, how should you know whether the padding changed or not?

Comment: I have one container i want to load my html page in that container but with different padding.I can manage to load page in container and change padding as well but not both at one time. Thats what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem before. The way I deal with it is to put the href stuff inside the function as well, otherwise the click can only trigger either href or the function.

Please try the following, or similar:

```
<a href="/Link1/" onclick="return SizeOf();">LinkText</a>

function SizeOf() {
   document.getElementById("contain1").style.padding = "...";
   window.location.href = '/Link1/';
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it is opening in new tab.

Comment: @nmahale How about you try `window.location.href = '/Link1/';`

Comment: Still not able to get.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`mousedown`** it will trigger before redirect the link.so both thing's will append

```js
function SizeOf() {
       document.getElementById("contain1").style.padding = "000px 150px 00px     210px";
  
         }
```

```html
<a  href="/Link1/" onmousedown="SizeOf() " target="_top" >LinkText</a>

  <p id="contain1">contain</p>
```

Comment: I have tried this .But my link is getting opened in new tab.

Comment: try with `target="_top"` in `a` tag .see my updated answer